# How to reset Pipewire settings?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, audio, kde

I got a new microphone and was messing with all the audio settings in KDE, but now my old headset mic doesn't work (and my options are really messed up). On Pulse audio you could just delete `~/.config/pulse`, but Pipewire's [Wiki](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Troubleshooting) shows the configs in `~/.config/pipewire`, which doesn't exist on my system.

How can I delete/reset Pipewire's config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In sufficiently recent PipeWire releases settings are managed by WirePlumber whose settings are stored in the `$HOME/.local/state/wireplumber/` directory.

Some distros still use pipewire-media-session which is being deprecated. In this case the directory is `$HOME/.local/state/pipewire/media-session.d/`.

Delete this directory and restart to reset all the settings.

Comment: I have a similar directory - `$HOME/.local/state/pipewire/media-session.d/`. Can I just delete it?

Comment: Yes, some distros still use pipewire-media-session which is being deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

This didn't work for me - so I fired up a live instance of Dragonized KDE and copied the files across from `$HOME/.local/state/wireplumber/` directory in the live instance to replace the files my installed instance. That worked just fine.